# PHP: Transform numbers into encoded string of fixed length

Tags: php, string, encoding

I have a lot of numbers.. some are one digit and other are with many digits. I need to create a string for each number. The string must have length of 8 characters (always).

I tried with base64encode that gives me a nice string for each number... but for a one digit number i only have 3 characters.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of digits?

Answer (score 2):

```
$substitutes = range('a', 'j');
$formatted   = sprintf('%010d', $number);
$string      = preg_replace_callback('/./', function ($m) use ($substitutes) {
                   return $substitutes[$m[0]];
               }, $formatted);

echo $string;
```

And this is virtually the "brute force" version, I'm sure there are even quicker ways to do this. I'll let you figure those out together with the decoding algorithm.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really help me. You just fill up the string with a at the beghinning. That's not pretty

Comment: What else do you want?